# Subir archivos en Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Tengo una duda sobre drupal 8, anteriormente maneje drupal, pero con un tema preestablecido, este tenia un modulo u opción para subir imágenes, documentos etc, tengo otra página pero no tiene ese mismo modulo, aquí el ejemplo:

[image: Imagen sin la opción de búsqueda]

pero aquí en este drupal si esta la otra opción ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi pregunta es ¿debo instalar un plugin o modulo para tener esta función ó es causa del tema que se usa en esta versión?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El módulo que necesitas activar es un módulo del núcleo de Drupal que viene desactivado por defecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez lo activas, ya puedes acceder a el en la ruta

```
/admin/content/media
```